# Capture SSIS runtime variables

Tags: c#, ssis, bids

I have an SSIS package with several variables in the User:: namespace. I am hopeless pathetic in C# programming. I would like to gather (loop through) each variable and its value to be used in a For Each container that will use an SQL Task to write the variable Name and value to a database table. I dont want the package to be interrupted by using the watch window and such.  Ive scoured the interwebs and havent found a viable solution. Please Assist and Yes it has to be in C# due to management mandate but that is a whole other argument.
TIA

Comment: Help me understand the For Each part. The intention is that you'd iterate through a list of all the User scoped variables and then call a method that records the variable name and it's value? Guessing here so if you could refine your question to clarify what your end goal is as well as your constraints, I think I can assist here.

Comment: What is the objective you are trying to achieve with this process?  Are you processing through files, fields in different tables, etc?  It sounds like you are trying to gather multiple record results using a SQL statement in one task and assign that to a variable defined as an object (basically an array) and then apply that object variable in an loop that will process each value in the object (array) one at a time some C# code.  Is that your basic objective?